# 3 grid layout: fixed sidebars and fluid content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a layout whose its structure is a mixed-type. I want two sidebars: one in the left side, another in the right side - both of them has 250px of width; in the middle, I just want the content whose its width is fluid.

I can make some math to solve my problem like `calc(100% - 500px)`, but I really don't want to use CSS3 for this – I want a cross-browser solution, and it can be pure CSS2 or JavaScript.

Can someone suggest me something? It can be a grid system, functions, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="center"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

css

```
.left{
    width: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
.center{
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    left: 250px;
    right: 250px;
}
.right
    width: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the document width:
   `var documentWidth = $(document).width();`
2. Remove the 'px':
   `documentWidth = documentWidth.split('px')[0];`
3. Calculate the width of the middle div:
   `var middleDivWidth = documentWidth - 500;`
4. Set the calculated width to the middle div: 
   `$('#middleDivId').css('width',middleDivWidth+'px');`

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.div1 {
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
}
.div2 {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: auto;
    float:left;
}
.div3 {
    width: 250px;
    float: right;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8LR4e/1/)